# identify dynamically created svg element

Tags: javascript, svg, element, identify

I am trying to manipulate elements inside `svg` (such as circle or path). I need to create them dynamically and be able to identify them.

I've stolen few functions from some online examples, and came up with following code (it should create circle inside svg on mouse click, and a text tag when the mouse is over the circle). However, it is not working as I expected. When mouse enters the element from left, the `elementFromPoint(x, y).id` returns `valid ID "circle"`, but when the mouse enters the element from right, it returns it's parent ID "mySVG".

I was not able to find a proper solution anywhere, so any advice is welcomed - indeed, I will try to read the specs for svg and learn JS as best as I can, however, it is still a painful process for me to understand these things. Your time and suggestions are highly appreciated! Thanks. k

JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/krisfiddle/2xc3tgdr/6/

The Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <style>
        body, canvas, svg {position:absolute; margin:0; padding:0; border:none;}

        svg {top:0; left:0;}

        .circle:hover {opacity:0.5;}

    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <svg id="mySVG" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="400" width="300" style="border: 1px solid black" onClick="circle()"></svg>

    <script>
        var w = window.innerWidth;
        var h = window.innerHeight;
        var x;
        var y;
        var color = undefined;

       function handleMouseMove(event) {
            var dot, eventDoc, doc, body, pageX, pageY;

            event = event || window.event;

            if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
                eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
                doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
                body = eventDoc.body;

                event.pageX = event.clientX +
                  (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
                  (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
                event.pageY = event.clientY +
                  (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) -
                  (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0 );
            }

            x = event.pageX;
            y = event.pageY;
            }
        document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;

        function circle() {
            var myCircle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
            myCircle.setAttribute('id', 'circleID');
            myCircle.setAttribute('class', 'circle');
            myCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", x);
            myCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", y);
            myCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "r", 50);
            myCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "green");
            myCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "none");
            myCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseover", "getIdXY()");
            myCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout", "deleteIdXY()");
            document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(myCircle); 
        }

        function getIdXY() {
        var elementMouseIsOver = document.  
        var idMark = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
        idMark.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
        idMark.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y);
        idMark.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "red");
        idMark.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "text");
        document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(idMark);
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = elementMouseIsOver;
        }

        function deleteIdXY() {
            var parent = document.getElementById("mySVG");
            var child = document.getElementById("text");
            parent.removeChild(child);
        }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, for the time being, I implemented both sugestions by Robert and Marcin. For some reason the elementFromPoint() seems to be quite difficult for me to handle in this particular implementation, thus I gladly turned to "this obj" method. Indeed, storing coords in global variables and asigning unique ID to elements is a good idea. Thought the code is not very elegant it gave me a good intro into JS and dynamicaly created SVG. Many thans to Marcin and Robert. The result is sutisfactory for my purposes at the moment and can be observed at following fiddle in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/4uu1vbzz/2/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <svg id="mySVG" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="400" width="300" style="border: 1px solid black"></svg>    
</body>

<script>
var x, y, recentX, recentY; // stores XY mouse coordinations
var circleID = 0; // used as increment to generate unique ID for each circle
var tagID = 0; // used as increment to generate unique ID for each circle's tag
var elementMouseIsOver = ""; // stores ID of the element recently under the pointer

// get mouse coords on mouse move   
var mouseMoves = function(e) {
    recentX = e.clientX;
    recentY = e.clientY;
    }
    window.onload = function() {this.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoves);} //event handler for mousemove coords

//create circle within svg  
var draw = function draw(e) {
    x = e.clientX; 
    y = e.clientY;

    circleID = circleID + 1; //increment the number for ID
    var id = "circle" + circleID; //create string to pass the ID

    //place circle with ID into svg
    var myCircle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");        
    myCircle.setAttribute('id', id);
    myCircle.setAttribute('class', 'circle');
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", x);
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", y);
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "r", 50);
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "green");
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "none");
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseover", "tagId(this)");
    myCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout", "deleteTag()");
    document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(myCircle);
    }
    document.getElementById("mySVG").addEventListener('click', draw); //event handler for onclick action

//on mouseover get the ID of the element under the pointer and create an tag marking it
function tagId(obj) {
    elementMouseIsOver = obj.id;
    tagID = tagID + 1;
    var id = "tag" + tagID;
    var idMark = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
    idMark.setAttributeNS(null, "x", recentX);
    idMark.setAttributeNS(null, "y", recentY);
    idMark.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "red");
    idMark.setAttributeNS(null, "id", id);
    document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(idMark);
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = elementMouseIsOver;
    }

//remove the tag when mouse leaves the element  
function deleteTag() {
    var id = "tag" + tagID;
    var parent = document.getElementById("mySVG");
    var child = document.getElementById(id);
    parent.removeChild(child);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your structure is all wrong.

Get the current coordinates of the click in your click handler, and keep some kind of counter outside of the handler (but accessible to it), which you increment every time you create a circle. That way, you can add that number to circleID.

Comment: thank you for the instructions, I will try to implement these. Much appreciated! k